# mover dados para a esquerda no pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from unicodedata import normalize 

tabelas = pd.read_html('https://www.msn.com/pt-br/esportes/basquete/nba/estatisticas-de-times')
for i in tabelas:
  print(i)

tabelas[0].head()
```

Os dados estão diferentes do site, as linhas estão 'fora' das colunas corretas.
Preciso mover a linha para a esquerda, assim os dados ficarão corretos.

```
    Posição  TIME         TIME.1   GP  ...  LLC  TDAL  %LL  Unnamed: 14
0         1   NaN           Nets  Bkn  ...  409   576  705          817
1         2   NaN          Bucks  Mil  ...  395   444  608          730
2         3   NaN  Trail Blazers  Por  ...  389   486  591          822
3         4   NaN           Jazz  Uta  ...  393   499  643          776
4         5   NaN       Clippers  LAC  ...  422   525  624          841
5         6   NaN        Nuggets  Den  ...  378   451  581          776
6         7   NaN       Warriors   GS  ...  374   509  655          777
7         8   NaN          76ers  Phi  ...  362   611  779          784
8         9   NaN          Bulls  Chi  ...  380   443  558          794
9        10   NaN       Pelicans   NO  ...  368   509  694          733
10       11   NaN        Raptors  Tor  ...  385   524  635          825
11       12   NaN        Wizards  Was  ...  342   530  695          763
12       13   NaN          Kings  Sac  ...  368   467  651          717
13       14   NaN         Pacers  Ind  ...  371   463  598          774
14       15   NaN          Hawks  Atl  ...  354   608  741          821
15       16   NaN      Mavericks  Dal  ...  350   515  656          785
16       17   NaN         Lakers  LAL  ...  358   518  691          750
17       18   NaN      Grizzlies  Mem  ...  371   364  462          788
18       19   NaN        Hornets  Cha  ...  379   444  579          767
19       20   NaN           Suns  Pho  ...  362   414  496          835
20       21   NaN          Spurs   SA  ...  358   460  580          793
21       22   NaN        Celtics  Bos  ...  376   471  619          761
22       23   NaN        Rockets  Hou  ...  340   466  621          750
23       24   NaN   Timberwolves  Min  ...  357   435  579          751
24       25   NaN        Pistons  Det  ...  354   532  679          784
25       26   NaN        Thunder  OKC  ...  343   433  587          738
26       27   NaN           Heat  Mia  ...  352   487  618          788
27       28   NaN          Magic  Orl  ...  350   454  581          781
28       29   NaN      Cavaliers  Cle  ...  337   464  646          718
29       30   NaN         Knicks   NY  ...  357   493  644          766

[30 rows x 15 columns]
```

Comment: "*as linhas estão 'fora' das colunas corretas*", poderia apontar exatamente o que está errado?

Comment: Os dados estão fora de ordem, o correto seria na coluna GP ficaria o valor de 31 na coluna PPG o valor 121.3 assim por diante. Igual ao site que eu exportei os dados https://www.msn.com/pt-br/esportes/basquete/nba/estatisticas-de-times/sp-s-pts

Comment: Acredito que os valores das colunas estao errado pois apareceu um nova coluna, TIME.1, e os valores corretos ficaram na coluna seguinte. Ex: 817 deveria está na coluna  %LL, é isso?

Comment: Correto, exclui essas colunas e mesmo assim os dados continuam fora de ordem.

Comment: Ja tentou excluir a coluna TIME e renomear as demais colunas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, minha solução foi renomar as colunas, da seguinte forma:

Alterei o seu dataset "tabelas" para o nome df.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from unicodedata import normalize 

tabelas = pd.read_html('https://www.msn.com/pt-br/esportes/basquete/nba/estatisticas-de-times')
for i in tabelas:
  print(i)

df = tabelas[0]
df.head()
```

Depois renomeei as colunas

```
df = df.drop(columns = ['TIME'])
df.rename(columns = {'TIME.1':'TIME', 'GP':'Abrev_Time', 'PPG':'GP','AC':'PPG', 'TDA':'AC', '%AC':'TDA', '3PM':'%AC', '3PA':'3PM', '3P%':'3PA', 'LLC':'3P%', 'TDALL':'LLC', '%LL':'TDALL', 'Unnamed: 14':'%LL'}, inplace = True)
df
```

P.S - Você precisa dividir a coluna %AC por 10, pois o python não aceita vírgula.

Comment: Solução inteligente a baixíssimo custo de processamento.

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda, interessante essa forma também.

Answer (score 2):

Segue uma possível solução, fazendo o fatiamento, depois utilizando o shift para mover as colunas

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

tabelas = pd.read_html('https://www.msn.com/pt-br/esportes/basquete/nba/estatisticas-de-times') 

df = tabelas[0].copy()

df.loc[:,'TIME':'%LL'] = df.loc[:, 'TIME':'Unnamed: 14'].shift(-1, axis=1).drop('Unnamed: 14', axis=1)
df.drop('Unnamed: 14', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Saída

| Posição | TIME | TIME.1 | GP | PPG | AC | TDA | %AC | 3PM | 3PA | 3P% | LLC | TDAL | %LL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nets | Bkn | 31 | 121.3 | 1.356 | 2.702 | 502 | 471 | 1.151 | 409 | 576 | 705 | 817 |
| 2 | Bucks | Mil | 29 | 119.6 | 1.295 | 2.652 | 488 | 435 | 1.102 | 395 | 444 | 608 | 730 |
| 3 | Trail Blazers | Por | 28 | 115.8 | 1.15 | 2.574 | 447 | 457 | 1.176 | 389 | 486 | 591 | 822 |
| 4 | Jazz | Uta | 29 | 115.6 | 1.186 | 2.543 | 466 | 482 | 1.227 | 393 | 499 | 643 | 776 |
| 5 | Clippers | LAC | 30 | 115.4 | 1.254 | 2.584 | 485 | 430 | 1.019 | 422 | 525 | 624 | 841 |
| 6 | Nuggets | Den | 28 | 115.4 | 1.204 | 2.51 | 480 | 371 | 981.0 | 378 | 451 | 581 | 776 |
| 7 | Warriors | GS | 29 | 114.7 | 1.199 | 2.588 | 463 | 418 | 1.119 | 374 | 509 | 655 | 777 |
| 8 | 76ers | Phi | 29 | 114.6 | 1.205 | 2.507 | 481 | 302 | 834.0 | 362 | 611 | 779 | 784 |
| 9 | Bulls | Chi | 27 | 114.6 | 1.143 | 2.389 | 478 | 364 | 958.0 | 380 | 443 | 558 | 794 |
| 10 | Pelicans | NO | 28 | 114.6 | 1.183 | 2.459 | 481 | 335 | 911.0 | 368 | 509 | 694 | 733 |

...

Comment: Se pudesse dava outro +1 só pelo trabalho de montar essa tabela.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, resolveu o meu problema. Agora partirei para as análises